# How do I get the following Table name: Supplementary Table S1?

Tags: tables, overleaf

I want my table name to be "Supplementary Table S1".

I used the command

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{Supplementary Table S\arabic{table}}
```

but this returns "Table Supplementary Table S1." How can I remove the "Table" at the beginning of the table name?

Answer (score 2):

`\thetable` only prints the running number of the table counter. The prefix is defined by `\tablename`. Thus, the simple solution is redefining `\tablename`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\tablename}{Supplementary Table S}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{A table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

For a more detailed approach you can use the `caption` package. From your question its not clear if **Supplementary Table S1** should be the whole caption, or if there still follows a caption text after it. For the former style, you could use this code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mytable}{#1#2}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Supplementary Table S}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=mytable,labelsep=none}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
    \caption{}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, only the format of tables is changed. If you want a caption text to appear behind the label just delete the key `labelsep=none` or replace it with a wanted seperator.